# Show bank transaction details in a grid view

Tags: asp.net

I have to show the bank transaction details in a grid view.
i have a form in which there are 2 textbox one for credit,and other for debit.when user click on submit button, credit,debit and Balance shows in gridview.
Balance=Balance+(credit-debit)
My problem is that when user entered the new debit or credit value, it should be add or subtract from last stored balance in database and grid view shoes the whole transaction.

Comment: You didn't describe a problem, you described your intention, how you want this to work. Tell us exactly which part of your code is giving you problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your issue is that the starting Balance column in your Gridview for every row is the same.

Instead of making Balance an expression where Balance = Balance + Credit - Debit, why not iterate through the GridView and do something like this:

```
int balance; // grab the balance from the database here.

foreach(DataRow row in TransactionTable.Rows)
{
   balance = balance + row["Credit"] - row["Debit"];
   row["Balance"] = balance;
}
```